# Virtualized Puppet master showing alphanumeric error when trying to load the dashboard

Tags: virtual, html, puppet

When I try to go to the puppet dashboard it loads up a white page saying

The environment must be purely alphanumeric, not ''

I googled this error a bit but there does not seem to be a finite solution yet. As fast as what I've done I've looked into the conf.d files, but I'm afraid to make the wrong edit. I'm still new to this and was wondering if anyone has ever ran into a similar situation?

Comment: This error occur when you try to access the puppet master daemon with your browser instead of your dashboard. You should review your virtualhost settings in apache.

Comment: What do you mean access the demon with the browser instead of dashboard? You're supposed to access the dashboard through the browser.

I get that the virtualhost settings may have something to do with it, but I'm not really sure where to begin to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if one tries to access puppet console in wrong port (8140) instead of 443, assuming default ports are being used.

Comment: Yup, that was the issue. So simple.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when you install puppet-passenger The opensource.
In this case - everything is OK!

Install Open Source agent and be a Puppet Master :)